# Can we call scala functions polymorphic by parameter without shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm talking about this (and only about parametric polymorphism):

```
def fun1[T](s: Set[T]): Option[T] = s.headOpton
```

I've seen in a few places when people call this an example of polymorphic function around `T` in raw scala - something like in shapeless `Set ~> Option`.

But I do not understand why we can call it polymorphic. Even though we seem to be able to pass there both `Set[Int]` and `Set[String]` in reality `fun1[Int]` and `fun1[String]` are two different functions. I think I can claim that because eta-expansion of `fun1` is wrong and does not give us what we want:

```
scala> fun1 _
res0: Set[Nothing] => Option[Nothing] = <function1>
```

And we need to always mention a type when we expand:

```
scala> fun1[Int]_
res1: Set[Int] => Option[Int] = <function1>
```

I am trying to study shapeless and I try to compare it with the raw scala - that's where the question is coming from. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Sorry @Archeg but are you asking why `fun1` is a parametric polymorphic function?

Comment: @Filippo I ask am I right to claim that it isn't. But if I am wrong - then surely the question is "why?" :)

Comment: The confusion around the terminology here is partly because it's actually confusing and partly because the limitations of the JVM make it confusing. `fun1` is a polymorphic method, but it's not a polymorphic function (or "polymorphic function value"), and it's not possible to have a polymorphic function in Scala (except by coming up with an altogether different way of encoding functions, like Shapeless's `Poly`).

Comment: [This article](http://milessabin.com/blog/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/) expands on @TravisBrown's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun1` implementation is not dependent on the type `T` therefore it is written *generically*:

> Using parametric polymorphism, a function or a data type can be
>   written generically so that it can handle values identically without
>   depending on their type.

(source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism))

I agree when you mention that `fun1[Int]` and `fun1[String]` "are two different functions". These are adopting a "concrete type":

> Parametric polymorphism refers to when the type of a value contains
>   one or more (unconstrained) type variables, so that the value may
>   adopt any type that results from substituting those variables with
>   concrete types.

(source [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Polymorphism))

---

**EDIT** after @Travis and @Miles comments:

As Travis clearly explained, we can have *polymorphic methods* in "plain scala" but not *polymorphic functions*. In [this article](http://milessabin.com/blog/2012/05/10/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-2/) Miles implements using `Poly` exactly the polymorphic function mentioned in this question:

```
object headOption extends PolyFunction1[Set, Option] {
  def apply[T](l: Set[T]): Option[T] = l.headOption
}

scala> headOption(Set(1, 2, 3))
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: I agree with you, but this does not explain my question. In scala function should have eta-expansion, but `fun1` does not have. I think Travis comment to the question explains a lot.

Comment: I agree with you, Travis actually explain why `fun1` is not a polymorphic function but a polymorphic method